# Расширение подсветки синтаксиса

Tags: vim, vimrc

По умолчанию, в подсветке синтаксиса для c, vim никак не подсвечивает операторы вроде = или + и т.д. Для их подсветки я добавил несколько строк в c.vim файл, который отвечает за синтаксис c. Все работает, но мне не хотелось бы для этого редактировать этот файл, а, к примеру, просто добавить соответствующую логику в файл vimrc. Возможно ли это?